# How do I programmatically add pages to a wiki library in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

My first question on stackoverflow, I hope I am following the rules.

Anyhow, as the title suggests, I need to figure out how to programmatically add pages to a wiki library.  I set up upwards of 30,000 rows in Excel, VBA'd them into txt files containing html that portray articles, and now they are sitting in a folder with nowhere to go.  They need to go into a wiki library on SharePoint, where they will be referenced by users in their articles.  Two parts:

1. On single-file upload, cannot upload aspx files.  I upload as txt or html and it goes fine.  Then I try to change them to aspx.  Illegal.
2. Cannot upload more than one file at a time.  Once I figure out #1, this will be an issue.

I assumed there must be a way to mimic whatever the "wikification" process is for files programmatically.  Microsoft's how-to on file uploading requires a Sharepoint Project, which requires VS Professional and running SharePoint locally.  Neither of these is practical.

Thank you and godspeed.

Comment: Not sure to understand. You can't use VS, you don't have SharePoint on premise. What's your environment ? SharePoint online ?

Comment: VS 2012 Express and SP Online.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small Powershell Script or Commandline application for example in C# or VB. Copy your files to the server and execute your script/app on the SharePoint server. Connect to your SharePoint like the following:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

...

SPSite site = new SPSite("mysiteurl");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

// your code goes here

web.dispose();
site.dispose();

...
```

Then get the directory programmatically where your files reside.

If this was successful, loop through all files in your folder and upload them programmatically to the WIKI Library.

Sound complex, but if you search for the single topics, you will find a lot of solutions/code out there.

You could also write a Console Application which can connect remotely to the SharePoint Server without the need to be executed on the SharePoint itself. In this case you would need to use the Client Object Model (CSOM).

Answer (score 0):

The Office 365 Patterns and Practices site is a great reference. It has a comprehensive sample for creating wiki pages using CSOM [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Provisioning.Pages)